# Outlook and Excel VBA integration for Auto Reports

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Because I am unable to set a rule in Outlook to run a VBA script, I tried to create a workaround.

When a certain daily email comes in with an attachment, I want to download the excel attachment and open an excel workbook and run a vba script in that excel to update information, update charts, save the file, and send the file as an email.

I am having trouble with the integration.  Ideally I would like to have Outlook automatically download an excel attachment when an email comes from a specific sender with a specific subject line, and then run excel vba script.

What I am currently doing is running a rule in Outlook that files the email in a sub-folder and having excel vba connect to outlook, find the email, download the file, and run code from excel, all when an email with "Test" in the subject line shows up in the default inbox.

I know this is long winded, but there has to be a better solution!  Please help  Here is my code so far:

**Outlook**:

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Set olApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  ' default local Inbox
  Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items

End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

 On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim oxl As Excel.Application
Dim owb As Excel.Workbook
Dim wsheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim asd As Object
Dim ExApp As Excel.Application
Dim ExWbk As Workbook
Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder


 If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then

Set Msg = item

    If Msg.Subject = "Test" Then

        Set ExApp = New Excel.Application
        Set ExWbk = ExApp.Workbooks.Open("excel file i want to open and run script")
        ExApp.Visible = False

        ExWbk.Application.Run "Module1.fromnew"

        Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
        Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder

        Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        Set myItems = myInbox.Items
         Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("Test")

        **Msg.Move myDestFolder**
'Not working

     End If

End If
 ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
  End Sub
```

**Excel**:

```
Sub fromnew()


Dim myd, myy As String
Dim newfile As Workbook
Dim prod As Workbook

Call Test

'Goes into Outlook and finds the email in an Outlook subfolder and downloads 'the excel attachment.  I want to remove this and have outlook automatically 'download the attachment so I don't have to call test()

myd = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
myy = Format(Date, "yyyy")

Set prod = ActiveWorkbook
Set newfile = Workbooks.Open("xyz\ds\" & myy & "\blahblahblah" & myd)


newfile.Sheets(1).Range("A1:AA7000").Copy Destination:=prod.Sheets("Data").Range("A1")
prod.Sheets("Data").Range("A2") = 1
newfile.Close
prod.Activate
prod.SaveAs ("here is a file name")



Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "email@xyz.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "here are your things"
    .Body = "Do you like beer?"
    .Attachments.Add ("here is a file name")
    .Send   
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
prod.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Which office are you running?

Answer (score -1):

you did not say why you are unable to set a rule in Outlook

you may have to change a key in windows registry to enable the execution of vba in a rule

do a web search for "EnableUnsafeClientMailRules" and read info from any microsoft.com page that comes up in the search

here is a link that is current today, but may change in future

it refers to outlook2013 and outlook2016

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3191893/how-to-control-the-rule-actions-to-start-an-application-or-run-a-macro